# How to run a function every n number of segues?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, func

Does anyone have decent code to run a function every n number of times a segue takes place? E.g. load an ad every time a user navigates 10 segues in my app.

At the moment I am doing something similar like so in my segue:

```
let chanceOfAd = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(9)))
```

and then if the chanceOfAd == 0 , then I will load an ad. This is not ideal as it is a 1/10 chance of loading the ad, not every 10 segues. Of course this should average out the same amount of ad loads as if I did the every ten option, but some users will inevitably receive more ads than others, through the luck nature of the function at the moment.

So instead I want to load the ad every 10 times the segue takes place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring a global variable that is incremented whenever the function `prepareForSegue` is called.

prepareForSegue might look something like this

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    segueCounter++
    if (segueCounter % 10 == 0) {
        //you know that on this segue you should load an ad.
        //do something like telling the destination view controller to show the ad
    }

    //...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either subclass or extend the `UIStoryBoardSegue` class and custom the `perfom :` method using a global variable.